# Cannot get data into UITableView in MasterViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, plist

I cannot get my .plist file to populate my table view in the masterviewcontroller. I am following a book and the code is exactly as written in the book but I am getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on thread 1 when running the code.

```
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var plantNames: [[String: String]]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("plantList", ofType: "plist")!
let plantInfo = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)!
plantNames = plantInfo["plants"]! as! [[String: String]]
```

I get the error on the final line. As far as I can tell, my .plist file matches everything that it would need to. If that needs to be posted as well then let me know.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Added .plist XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>plants</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Lily</string>
        <key>sunlight</key>
        <integer>30</integer>
        <key>water</key>
        <integer>40</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>water</key>
        <integer>5</integer>
        <key>sunlight</key>
        <integer>80</integer>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Cactus</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>sunlight</key>
        <integer>100</integer>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Bonsai Tree</string>
        <key>water</key>
        <integer>50</integer>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: The reason is either the key `plants` does not exist or `plantInfo["plants"]` is not `[[String: String]]`

Comment: I'm confident that plants exists, I have added my plist file to the post. What do you mean plantInfo["plants"] is not [[String: String]]?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on that line and type `po plantInfo` in the debugger console, what do you see?

Comment: This is what I get with that command: po plantInfo
▿ 1 elements
  ▿ [0] : 2 elements
    - .0 : plants
    ▿ .1 : 3 elements
      ▿ [0] : 4 elements
        ▿ [0] : 2 elements
          - .0 : soil
          - .1 : Chalk
        ▿ [1] : 2 elements
          - .0 : sunlight
        ▿ [2] : 2 elements
          - .0 : water
        ▿ [3] : 2 elements
          - .0 : name
          - .1 : Lily
      ▿ [1] : 4 elements
        ▿ [0] : 2 elements
          - .0 : soil { ... }
          - .1 : Alkali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in the dictionary contain `String` and `Int` types so you have to declare `plantNames` as `[[String:AnyObject]]` and a data source array is supposed to be always non-optional.

```
var plantNames: [[String: AnyObject]]()

...

plantNames = plantInfo["plants"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
```

But now you have to cast any value you retrieve from the dictionary to `String` or `Int`.

Side-note: When forced downcasting a type the exclamation mark after the key subscription is not needed.

Alternatively change all `Int` types to `String` in the property list file to avoid type casting.

Comment: Would changing all of the types in the plist file to string fix this in a dirty-ish way?

Comment: I took the easy way out and changed them all to strings, thank you!